# Does compass-rails support Ruby on Rails 4.0?

Tags: compass-sass, ruby-on-rails-4

I have clean new Rails 4 app with Gemfile:

```
#default gems
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'zurb-foundation'
gem 'thin'
```

with style.scss:

```
@import "compass";
@import "foundation/variables";
$red: rgb(255,0,1);
$green: rgb(51,153,50);
$body-bg: #F4F4F4;
$body-font-color: #7B7B7B;
$primary-color: #999;
$secondary-color: #0CC;
$dark-color: #393939;
$block-container-border-color: rgb(218,218,218);
$block-container-shadow-color: rgb(208,208,208);
// main background
html{
  background:image-url('bckg.jpg');
}
body{
  width:1000px;
  margin:0 auto;
  @include box-shadow(0px 0px 32px -5px #000);
}
```

And I have this error:

```
Showing /Users/quatermain/Projects/rails40/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #18 raised:

File to import not found or unreadable: compass.
Load paths:
  /Users/quatermain/Projects/rails40/app/assets/images
  /Users/quatermain/Projects/rails40/app/assets/javascripts
  /Users/quatermain/Projects/rails40/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/quatermain/Projects/rails40/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /Users/quatermain/Projects/rails40/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/turbolinks-1.2.0/lib/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/jquery-rails-3.0.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/coffee-rails-4.0.0/lib/assets/javascripts
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/zurb-foundation-4.2.3/scss
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/zurb-foundation-4.2.3/js
  (in /Users/quatermain/Projects/rails40/app/assets/stylesheets/style.scss:5)
```

Is Rails 4 not currently supported by `compass-rails`?

Comment: I'm also attempting to create a new rails 4 application with compass-rails and Foundation, and am having no luck. I can't find any evidence that compass-rails does support rails 4 yet, but I can't find any documentation of the contrary either..

Comment: I'm the new maintainer of compass-rails. The compass-rails 1.1.x series of gems works on Rails 4. It wasn't getting much attention for a while and people started using unofficial forks to get Rails 4 support. I can assure you that going forward I'll be responsive to issues and continue to release support for upcoming version of Compass and Rails so compass-rails will be as seamless an experience as possible.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

<strike>Compass needs to have some key parts rewritten in order to support Rails 4. There is a temporary branch you can use that has hacked together some support:</strike>

`'gem "compass-rails", github: "milgner/compass-rails", ref: "1749c06f15dc4b058427e7969810457213647fb8"`

You can follow https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails/pull/59 for the latest updates.

Update:

<strike>There is now a version in alpha.</strike>

`gem "compass-rails", "~> 2.0.alpha.0"`

Update 2:
compass-rails is no longer in alpha.

Add the following to your Gemfile and type `bundle install`.

```
gem "compass-rails", "~> 1.1.2"
```

Comment: It's a real bummer that such a widely used gem is getting neglected like this. Hopefully official support will be available soon.

Comment: The milgner/compass-rails repository has gone now

Comment: Yes, people should be using the alpha as I indicated. I'll cross out the old section.

Comment: The 2.0.alpha.0 gem has now been yanked, for some reason, breaking our deploy process. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: See my answer below. Just use the stable branch (no version string) in your Gemfile and run `bundle update`.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using the alpha version suggested by Sunny Juneja.

But to make it work I had to remove the assets group from my gemfile:

```
# Not working:
group :assets do       # remove me olde line
   gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 4.0.0'
   gem 'compass-rails' # specify me version
end                    # remove me too, says aye

# Working:
gem 'sass-rails',    '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'compass-rails', '~> 2.0.alpha.0'
```

Comment: This is because in Rails 4 support for group assets was dropped. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406204/why-did-rails4-drop-support-for-assets-group-in-the-gemfile

Answer (score 3):

As of about 18 hours ago, the stable branch of compass-rails supports Rails 4. Remove the version string "2.0.alpha.0" from compass-rails in your Gemfile and run `bundle update`.

Here's the commit history:

https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails/commits/stable

Answer (score 0):

It appears that as of this time (06/29/2013) compass-rails does not support Rails 4. When I run

```
rails generate foundation:install
```

I get the error message below.

```
Unsupported rails environment for compass
```

Comment: Wrong. compass-rails *does* support Rails 5 or later

Answer (score 0):

I added all of the compass files to my vendor folder and it worked =), this may not be the preferable option for much longer =(.

Comment: Sunny Juneja solution is working, so you do not need using "vendor"

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'compass-rails', github: 'Compass/compass-rails'
```

You should also make sure these are NOT included inside your asset group, since it has been removed from Rails 4.0.

Then remove your `Gemfile.lock` file and regenerate it using the `bundle` command.

```
rm Gemfile.lock
bundle
```