# Rails App: Precompiling assets failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, turbolinks

I'm trying to push my rails app to Heroku, but I got this error:

"couldn't find file 'turbolinks' - however 'turbolinks" is in my gemfile (attached).

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
    gem 'turbolinks'
    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
end

group :doc do
    gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 doesn't use the `:assets` group anymore. See http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0 and discussion from SO here: [Why did Rails4 drop support for "assets" group in the Gemfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406204/why-did-rails4-drop-support-for-assets-group-in-the-gemfile).

Comment: Does this answer the question as to why the assets will not precompile? I created an app with Rails 4, do not have my assets listed as this person does, yet I still get an error.