# Sprockets::FileNotFound couldn't find file 'jquery-fileupload/basic'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-file-upload, sprockets, jquery-fileupload-rails

I am attempting to upload multiple pictures with jquery file upload. In my `application.js` file I added `//= require jquery-fileupload/basic` and in my `Gemfile` I added `jquery-fileupload-rails` under the assets group.  This causes the error: couldn't find file `jquery-fileupload/basic`.  I have reset my rails server and checked for spaces in `application.js` however the error stays.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require jquery.ui.tooltip
//= require jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min
//= require jquery.timepicker.min
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
//= require bootstrap/modal
//= require raty
//= require_tree .
```

gemfile

```
gem 'byebug', '~> 3.5.1'
gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'pg'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'
gem 'devise'
gem 'faker'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'state_machine'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.2.1'
gem 'rails_12factor'
gem 'elasticsearch-model'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-linkedin'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'pry-rails'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  # gem 'pry-debugger'
  gem 'meta_request'
  gem 'interactive_editor'
  gem 'hirb'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'awesome_print'
end
#
group :test do
    gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
    gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
end


gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'

group :assets do
    gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.2.1'
  gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put it outside the assets group and run `bundle install`.

btw `jquery-ui-rails` does not belong there either

Comment: what belongs in the the assets group?

Comment: I believe it was used for asset precompilers, like less, coffeescript, etc. In rails 4 the asset group does not even exist anymore. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406204/why-did-rails4-drop-support-for-assets-group-in-the-gemfile