# Rails and Foundation file not found or unreadable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, gemfile, compass

So I'm trying to get zurb foundation 5 to work with my Ruby on Rails app. There are many similar questions out there, but I've tried everything and nothing seems to work. Also most deal with foundation 4 so I feel that the other answers are outdated.

I'm getting a syntax error with the error message saying "File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/functions."

Here's my Gemfile:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'


    # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
    gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

    group :development, :test do
        # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
        gem 'sqlite3'
    end

    group :production do
        gem 'pg'
    end

    group :assets do
        # Use SCSS for stylesheets
        gem 'sass-rails'
        # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
        gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
        # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
        gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
        # Foundation
        gem 'foundation-rails'
        # Compass
        gem 'compass-rails'

    end 
    # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
    # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

    # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
    gem 'jquery-rails'
    # Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
    gem 'turbolinks'
    # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
    # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
    gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

    # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
    # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

    # Use Unicorn as the app server
    # gem 'unicorn'

    # Use Capistrano for deployment
    # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

    group :development, :test do
      # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
      gem 'byebug'

      # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using  in views
      gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

      # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
      gem 'spring'
    end
```

I had two versions of foundation, but I uninstalled the older one. I don't know what else the problem could be, and I appreciate any the help the community can give!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it could be a problem with the path settings, per [this item](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/6201) on the Foundation Github repo. If you go into app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss and edit the @import line to read:

```
@import 'foundation';
```

instead of:

```
@import 'foundation/functions';
```

Does that work? (that info from [this link](https://richonrails.com/articles/getting-started-with-zurb-foundation))

On a side note: I believe the assets group was removed in Rails4 ([Why did Rails4 drop support for "assets" group in the Gemfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406204/why-did-rails4-drop-support-for-assets-group-in-the-gemfile)). I'm guessing this doesn't affect the error you're getting, but might be worth cleaning up the code.