# Twitter-bootstrap-rails: does it install Bootstrap into a project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I do everything according to [Readme](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/blob/master/README.md) but having an issue when starting a rails app: **Sprockets::FileNotFound** And it points to `//= require twitter/bootstrap` Does this gem really install bootstrap stylesheets and corresponding js libraries or one is supposed to install them manually (with bower or in another way)? 
Here is my Gemfile:

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
group :assets do
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
end

gem 'responders', '~> 2.1.1'
gem 'haml'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'rspec-expectations', '~> 3.0.0'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  #gem 'guard-rspec', require: false
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0'
  # Support for its syntax
  gem 'rspec-its', '~> 1.0.1'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'ffaker'
  gem "bower-rails", "~> 0.10.0"
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'haml-rails'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Comment: This gem should make all the js and CSS of bootstrap library available to you. Have you restarted your server? Also, can you add your Gemfile to question.

Comment: @dkp Yes, I've restarted the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that because [`group assets` were dropped in Rails 4](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-2-to-rails-4-0-gemfile). From the docs:

> Rails 4.0 removed the assets group from Gemfile. You'd need to remove that line from your Gemfile when upgrading. You should also update your application file (in config/application.rb):

So instead of using it

```
....
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
group :assets do
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
end
....
```

Just remove the `group` block:

```
....
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
....
```

And then run `bundle install` and restart the server.

More info - [Why did Rails4 drop support for “assets” group in the Gemfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406204/why-did-rails4-drop-support-for-assets-group-in-the-gemfile)

Comment: You're welcome. Also, if the answer solved your problem, please accept it.