# Couldn't find file 'jquery-ui/datepicker'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Version Rails 5 beta 3.
I am using gem jquery-ui-rails 5.0.5

**gemfile**

```
group :assets do 
  # Use SCSS for stylesheets
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
  # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
  # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'  
end
```

application.js:

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require cocoon
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
```

**application.css**

```
/**
 * application.css
 *
 *= require jquery-ui/datepicker
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree ./all
*/
```

I installed all gems, restarted server, run project and displaying error: couldn't find file 'jquery-ui/datepicker' with type 'text/css'

Help, please.

Comment: File names have changed in jquery-ui-rails 5 - use //= require jquery-ui/all instead

Comment: i changet to /all, now display couldn't find file 'jquery-ui/all'

Comment: I haven't used RoR 5 (yet), but `group :assets` block [was dropped in RoR 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387206/twitter-bootstrap-rails-does-it-install-bootstrap-into-a-project/36387532#36387532). I doubt they returned it.

Comment: thank you. i deleted assets group, now without error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Rails 4 the `:assets` group in the Gemfile is no longer loaded.

It previously existed to avoid unwanted compile on demand - when the assets pipeline was redesigned it was no longer needed.

Just remove the `group :assets` block surrounding the gems.