# Bring "assets" bundler group back in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, bundler

Not sure why it was removed, but how would I go about adding the "assets" bundler group back into my Gemfile, and having it only be included for asset precomplication on deploy (as well as development etc.)? Basically, to recreate the functionality that was already present in Rails 3.

My rationale is to reduce runtime memory usage, since the gems I would put into that group are only really needed during asset precompilation.

Also, is there any inherent reason why this would be a bad idea? I deploy to Heroku, in case that makes any difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why did Rails4 drop support for "assets" group in the Gemfile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406204/why-did-rails4-drop-support-for-assets-group-in-the-gemfile)

Comment: @Leito that question discusses why it was dropped and what the ramifications are. I'm looking for a workaround to get the same functionality as the old.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just saying this is a possible duplicate because you aren't sure why it was removed, that's discussed in length in that question and linked commits. Your question is too vague, instead of discussing a proposed solution you are asking for one.